# NodeJS: Node-Onvif startProbe and startDiscovery don't work

Tags: node.js, onvif

Currently I'm trying to get local ip cameras via the node-onvif-package. All worked well until this afternoon, where the startProbe()-function doesn't find the cameras anymore.

```
onvif
  .startProbe()
  .then(device_info_list => {
    console.log(device_info_list.length + " devices were found.");

    // Use the list of cameras, gathered by onvif
    fullfill(device_info_list);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return reject(err);
  });
```

Is the code I'm using.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change the DiscoveryMode of the camera?

Comment: @OttavioCampana I'm using Ocular Ip Webcamera, where I can't really change anything besides the password (I already tried that)